# How to have iOS set a gradient on UIBarButtonItem image?

Tags: ios, customization, uibarbuttonitem, look-and-feel

just wondering, I customised the UIBarButtonItems the following way

```
+ (UIBarButtonItem *)createBarButtonItemWithTitle:(NSString *)t target:(id)tgt action:(SEL)a
{
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    UIImage *buttonImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"blabla.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 10, 0, 10)];


    CGRect buttonFrame = [button frame];
    buttonFrame.size.width = 35;
    buttonFrame.size.height = buttonImage.size.height;
    [button setFrame:buttonFrame];

    [button setBackgroundImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [button addTarget:tgt action:a forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    UIBarButtonItem *buttonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];

    return buttonItem ;
}
```

But now, I don't have the shading/glossy effect on the button background image....

Is there a way to have it done automatically, or I have to do it programatically ?

EDIT:
[image: Here is a capture, I used a simple green square to make it more obvious. There's no more shading/glossy effect]

Comment: Please share a screenshot of standard `UIBarButtonItem` where you can't do it with just an image.

Comment: ok, as shown with the image, no more shading/gloss. It's probably the normal behaviour, just wondering if I can get iOS to do it automatically...

Comment: As I see it, standard buttons have the same height, note how gloss effect looks - it's always plain horizontal (as far as I can remember). In this case, you'll want to add the gloss effect at the image and let it scale with no quality loss (giving insets to cover the border and corner areas). Works fast, looks great, I don't see any need to use or even make any special code for that.

Comment: Did you try calling [super] method first to get the UIBarButtonItem and then add your customizing to the button returned instead of creating a brand new button item?

Comment: @A-Live: sure, I can do that manually, it's just that it is not guaranteed to have the same image quality or same gradient. For AC1: no I did not try (plus that's a class method), in any case, since it's a direct alloc, the runtime should take care of calling the super class anyway, no?

Comment: Sorry, ignore my comment. It's actually irrelevant. I thought you override IOS's method.

Comment: Have you tried displaying the button created in the code above in a normal view instead of a bar item? Looking at the code above, I think it more likely to be how you create the resizable image in resizableImageWithCapInsets:. Is there a reason you aren't just using a normal image?

Comment: @daviddoyle : in fact after careful readings, there is no way to have the glossy/ shadow effect done automatically. The proper way is to actually do this in the image before it is added as a background(and not to use run time cocoa 2d processing.)  so I went through the painstaking processing via gimp. And did it once and for all.

Answer (score 0):

To totally customize the bar button in such a way you'd need to provide something other than the flat green image in "blabla.png".

A different way to handle this would be to create a bordered style button with your image. Something like:

```
UIBarButtonItem* barButton = [UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"blabla.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:tgt selector:a];
```

The `UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered` style gives it the 3D raised button-y look. You can tint its appearance to match your bar if desired.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Unfortunately, I instantiate a Button, not a UIBarButton, so this creates a nasty warning.

Comment: Well I guess I'm missing something. Your UIButton is just a green image. Then it looks like you are creating a UIBarButtonItem from that. Just skip the UIButton altogether and work with the UIBarButtonItem.

Comment: not really, I use the UIButton to initialise the UIBarButton with this custom UIView. This takes care of image stretching, adjustment as a function of the text length etc... Otherwise, there is no method to correctly assign an image and  variable text length at the same time on a UIBarButtonItem (at least none that I know of)

Comment: OK,that's not clear from the picture and description. You need to modify the stretchable image to include the effects you want. This could be done in code, but not automatically unfortunately.